Probability that random variables with multinomial distribution have a common divisor greater than 1
Consider an election in which $k$ candidates compete: Let $N_{i}$ denote the number of votes for candidate $i$ in the election.

How can we reasonably estimate the probability that the number of votes for each candidate in the election is a multiple of $a \in\mathbb N$ ?, that is, $N_{i}/a\in\mathbb N,\, i = 1,\ldots,k$.


The probability can be approximated as
$\left(1/a\right )^k$ based on a naïve approach, which considers that each number $N_i$ is a multiple of $a$ with approximate probability of $1/a,$ and assumes that the events $N_{i}/a\in\mathbb N,\, i = 1,\ldots, k$ are almost independent.
I suggest using the following approach by assuming $N_i, i=1,\dots,k$ follow a multinomial distribution:
$$
\sum_{i_{1} + \cdots + i_{k} = N\atop a|i_1,\dots, i_k } \binom {N}{i_1,\dots, i_k}p_1^{i_1}\cdots p_k^{i_k} \tag{1}
\label{1}
$$
where each $p_i$ can be well approximated by $N_{i}/N$ as $N$ is sufficiently large. This summation has $\binom{N/a + k - 1}{k - 1}$ terms.


Is there any efficient way to accurately compute the above probability ?.


What is the result for (taken from a real case)
\begin{align}
a = 3,\ N & = 24,535,185,\ N_{1} =,10,415,991,\ N_{2} = 9,473,298,
\\[2mm] N_{3} & = 3,383,340,\ N_{4} = 1,056,159,\ N_{5} = 206,397
\end{align}
The summation has about $10^{27}$ terms for this instance.

Two supplementary questions:

I am also wondering whether some bound on the difference of (\ref{1}) from $\left(1/a\right)^k$ can be obtained by imposing some conditions on $p_1, \dots, p_k$.
How can the probability that random variables with multinomial distribution have no common divisor greater than $1$ be computed ( there may be a simpler approach for this case ? ).


So you're saying: if each of the N voters vote uniformly and randomly between the k candidates, what is the probability that the gcd of all the vote numbers is greater one? Is that what you want to know?

@LeeFisher I am seeking an efficient way to compute the probability for arbitrary $p_1,\dots, p_k$. What you stated is a special case where $p_1=\dots= p_k=\frac{1}{k}.$

I don't think there's a nice formula. If you want to write a program to do this, maybe follow this outline: Unless $a$ is a factor $N$, the gcd of the partition cannot be $a$. Therefore, for each factor of $N$, $a > 1$ you should compute the ordered partitions of $N/a$ into $k$ parts, then sum them with their weights.

You would do this for primes which divide $N$ and then you have to do inclusion exclusion on the composites which divide $N$.

@LeeFisher you may note that in the main question $a$ is given and $a | N$ (see the example), which is very chalenging from a computational perspective. My last question is on the general case of having some arbitrary common divisor.
